# Send email for Graph Api works in Postman but not through App in Azure?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am accessing the Graph Api endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
```

I retrieve the access token from Graph Explorer and use it as a Bearer token in Postman.
I also set Content-Type in the header to "application/json".
I set the Body as

```
{
"message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "Text",
        "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "testuser@acme.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Through Graph Explorer I have given consent for Mail.Send
It works fine in Postman. I set the scope in my c# app as Mail.Send, but when i send the request it gives the error

{StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden'

What other permission do i need to set ?

Comment: Is your application using the client credentials flow? if so the /me endpoint won't work and you need to use /users/{id | userPrincipalName} endpoint

Comment: code snippet is required for us  to troubleshooting. an asp.net core application or console application?